# How to insert or add new row to the existing dat in one to many hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Have the two tables one is user and another is user address details.

Here user will add the new details and I need to insert  into the  many side table.

Here it is one to many relationalship. I have add new values to the table, without removing the existng relationalship.

But in my case what is happening is the old relationship get removed and new one get added.

entity class:

WashingOrder:

```
@Entity(name = "ClothDetails")
public class WashingOrder {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "orderNo", sequenceName = "orderNo")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "orderNo")
@Column(name = "orderNo")
private Long orderNo;

@Column(name = "totalClothes", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private Integer totalClothes;

@Column(name = "mensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer mensCloth;

@Column(name = "womensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer womensCloth;

@Column(name = "otherCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer otherClothes;

@Column(name = "deliveryDate", nullable = true)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
private Date deliveryDate;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = true)
private String orderStatus;

public Long getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}

public void setOrderNo(Long orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}

public Integer getTotalClothes() {
    return totalClothes;
}

public void setTotalClothes(Integer totalClothes) {
    this.totalClothes = totalClothes;
}

public Integer getMensCloth() {
    return mensCloth;
}

public void setMensCloth(Integer mensCloth) {
    this.mensCloth = mensCloth;
}

public Integer getWomensCloth() {
    return womensCloth;
}

public void setWomensCloth(Integer womensCloth) {
    this.womensCloth = womensCloth;
}

public Integer getOtherClothes() {
    return otherClothes;
}

public void setOtherClothes(Integer otherClothes) {
    this.otherClothes = otherClothes;
}

public Date getDeliveryDate() {
    return deliveryDate;
}

public void setDeliveryDate(Date deliveryDate) {
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
}

public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}

public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}
```

UserInformation:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class UserInformation   {

private String firstName;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userID", sequenceName = "userID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "userID")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String lastName;

@Column(name = "reset", nullable = false)
private Integer passwordReset;

@Column(name = "useremail", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Email
@NotEmpty
private String email;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Role role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private List<CreditCards> creditCards;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<WashingOrder> orderList;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "{username}")
private String username;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public List<CreditCards> getCreditCards() {
    return creditCards;
}

public void setCreditCards(List<CreditCards> creditCards) {
    this.creditCards = creditCards;
}

public Integer getPasswordReset() {
    return passwordReset;
}

public void setPasswordReset(Integer passwordReset) {
    this.passwordReset = passwordReset;
}

public List<WashingOrder> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public void setOrderList(List<WashingOrder> orderList) {
    this.orderList = orderList;
}
```

Code:

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    long id = 1;
    Query query = session.createQuery("from user where id =" + id);
    UserInformation emp6 = (UserInformation) session.load(UserInformation.class, new Long(1));
    UserInformation user = (UserInformation) query.uniqueResult();
    List<WashingOrder> washingOrder = new ArrayList<WashingOrder>();
    washingOrder.add(order);
    System.out.println("washingOrder" + washingOrder);
    emp6.setOrderList(washingOrder);
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);

    Long orderID = (long) 1;
    return orderID;
```

database screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post your entity class.

Comment: @Sandeep Patange entity class got added

Comment: Looking @ your DB image, what I'm understanding is when you try to add new variable/Column to entity, the previous values to the new column will becoming NULL. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @SandeepPatange: Yes you are write. When I add a new values to foreign value get removed first and the new values get added. NULL values should be "1", but it get removed when new value get added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update 'user', 'orderList' relations get updated too, because you have set 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL' on 'orderList'. Your code sample replaces orderList object with the totally new one. Therefore removing all previous relations, and adding a new one.

If you want to preserve relations and just adding a new one, you should use the list from the retrieved object:

```
List<WashingOrder> washingOrder = emp6.getOrderList();
washingOrder.add(order);
```

Make sure the 'orderList' is loaded beforehand, since you have lazy-loading enabled on that relation. You can do this with:

```
Hibernate.initialize(emp6.getOrderList());
```

Comment: There is any way to insert the orderList without  emp6.getOrderList();

Comment: There is any way to insert the orderList without  emp6.getOrderList(); I mean I dont want the old list to get load and then save the new one. I want simply save the new one

Comment: Sure, you could save the new List, but you need to add the old relations to the list, the ones you don't want to remove.